# Checking uploaded files

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

My django application uploads all files to my Amazon s3 storage bucket. So is there any reason for me to write code that cross-checks uploaded files to make sure they are not malicious? As an uploaded script in my s3 bucket can't really do any damage. The uploads are done via `URLField` or `FileField` (integrated with AJAX).

Comment: What is being done with the files?

Comment: If later on you are not going to: display it anywhere; allow it to be downloaded; Use it as part of any script; Publicity access any file. You should be fine. Most likely you have more chances on being warned by amazon (by storing something illegal) than you have on being harmed if all those conditions I've mentioned are followed